# Database management tool for compact edition (.sdf) database

Tags: sql-server

What is the best database management tool for remotely managing a compact edition (.sdf) database created in WebMatrix?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what it's the best, but one of the most popular is [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). 
Also many alternatives are listed at [ErikEJ's blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/).